# Uninstall the preinstalled PIL

Tags: python

I would like to install Pillow, but according to the Pillow's [documentation](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html), I must remove `PIL` first, <strike>which seems to have come preinstalled in Ubuntu 13.10.</strike>

What's the best way to do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way to uninstall pil is using [pip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pip_%28package_manager%29):

```
sudo pip uninstall pil
```

and then install pillow using pip:

```
sudo pip install pillow
```

(see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17601159/2223706) for installing pip)

Comment: Doing `sudo pip uninstall pil` gives the message: `Cannot uninstall requirement pil, not installed`.  And testing out `sudo pip uninstall pillow` seems to show that Ubuntu 13.10 comes preinstalled with Pillow, not PIL.  I was confused because `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/` has the directory: `PIL`, but I suppose that is referring to Pillow.  I notice there's also a directory called `Pillow-2.0.0.egg-info`.

Comment: It still shows up in `pip freeze` and I'm still having the issue that was supposedly fixed in Pillow. (Yes I installed Pillow after supposedly uninstalling PIP)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

Completely remove PIL/pillow (2.7 & 3.5):

```
$ sudo -H pip uninstall pillow
-> Successfully uninstalled Pillow-3.1.2
$ sudo -H pip3 uninstall pillow
-> Cannot uninstall requirement pillow, not installed
```

Completely remove pip & pip3:

```
$ which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip

$ /usr/local/bin/pip uninstall pip
$ sudo apt-get remove python-pip
```

Remove Egg (from easy_install):

Install pip & pip3:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-pip
$ sudo apt-get install python3-pip

$ sudo easy_install pip     <- Installs to different directory (egg)
$ sudo easy_install pip3    <- Installs to different directory (egg)
```

Install pillow (2.7 & 3.5):

```
sudo -H pip3 install pillow
-> Installed Pillow-4.1.1-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
sudo -H pip install pillow
-> Requirement already satisfied

$ sudo easy_install Pillow
Searching for Pillow
Best match: Pillow 4.1.1
Adding Pillow 4.1.1 to easy-install.pth file

Using /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Processing dependencies for Pillow
Finished processing dependencies for Pillow

$ sudo pip3 install Pillow
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```